# How to keep default image when updating a record in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

When a user updates a movie record and uploads a new image I want an older image to be deleted and a new one to be uploaded but if a movie has a default image I don't want to delete it (because other records with the default image won't have any after that) and just upload a new one during an update. And if a user doesn't upload anything then just keep a record with a default image like before while other parameters are getting updated. My code has some errors so here is the update function:

```
    public function update(StoreMovieRequest $request, Movie $movie)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('image_path') || $movie->image_path != 'images/default.png') {
            $deleteImage = unlink(public_path(). '/' . $movie->image_path);
            $image = $request->file('image_path');
            $imageDestinationPath = 'images/';
            $movieImage = $imageDestinationPath . date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($imageDestinationPath, $movieImage);
            $input['image_path'] = "$movieImage";
        } elseif($image = $request->file('image_path') || $movie->image_path == 'images/default.png') {
            $image = $request->file('image_path');
            $imageDestinationPath = 'images/';
            $movieImage = $imageDestinationPath . date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($imageDestinationPath, $movieImage);
            $input['image_path'] = "$movieImage";
        }
        $movie->update($input);
}
```

My migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('status')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->string('image_path')->default('images/default.png');
        });
    }
```

Model:

```
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'status', 'image_path'];
```

Request:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'image_path' => 'image',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: easier to leave the field null if there is no image and then supply the default in the blade view ?

Comment: @Snapey I have to do it this specific way because this is a task I was given

Comment: then you must test if the image name matches the default and skip the delete.  Can't think of anything clever to avoid that